# How to get non-latin input in console

Tags: c, winapi

I wanted to get Latin and also non-Latin characters as input but there is a problem here. When I am going to enter Persian words like (آزمایشی), in the console just I get ?????. How can I fix this issue in which I can get nonlatin input and save them in the wchar_t data type? I have used the following API to change the code page of the console, but it doesn't work.

```
void SetConsoleToUnicodeFont()
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
    {
        // Call the documented function.
        typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pfSetCurrentConsoleFontEx)(HANDLE, BOOL, PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
        HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
        pfSetCurrentConsoleFontEx pfSCCFX = (pfSetCurrentConsoleFontEx)GetProcAddress(hMod, "SetCurrentConsoleFontEx");

        CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfix;
        cfix.cbSize = sizeof(cfix);
        cfix.nFont = 12;
        cfix.dwFontSize.X = 8;
        cfix.dwFontSize.Y = 14;
        cfix.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
        cfix.FontWeight = 400;  // normal weight
        lstrcpyW(cfix.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");

        pfSCCFX(hConsole,
            FALSE, /* set font for current window size */
            &cfix);
    }
    else
    {
        // There is no supported function on these older versions,
        // so we have to call the undocumented one.
        typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pfSetConsoleFont)(HANDLE, DWORD);
        HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
        pfSetConsoleFont pfSCF = (pfSetConsoleFont)GetProcAddress(hMod, "SetConsoleFont");
        pfSCF(hConsole, 12);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the font, not the code page.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/national-language-support-functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your code encoding rule is `UTF-8 with signature`.

Then you need to modify the code page according to the text you output. For Farsi I'd expect you should use code page 1256.

Finally, modify the translation mode with [`_setmode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019) (make sure the version is higher than C++11).

Here is the sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
     SetConsoleOutputCP(1256);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"wordsزمایشی" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: `// Set console code page to UTF-8` - `SetConsoleOutputCP(1256);` - Those two lines of code do not agree.

Comment: In C, what I should use rather wcout?

Comment: I recommend you to use wprintf(L"%s", L"wordsزمایشی");