# Reading non-ascii characters in c using winapi

Tags: c, winapi

I got this callback function that reads output from `CreateThread` and outputs it to the console

```
DWORD grabOutput(LPVOID lpParam )
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRead, total =0;
    char buffer[1024];
    while(1)
    {
        success = ReadFile(Child_out_Read, buffer, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!success) break;
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when a non-ascii character passed through `printf` it results in such format `????` this is because the encoding used does not contain the string passed or at least this is what I understand, for example if the `Шифрование` is read into the buffer this word results in the undefined format of question marks, I know the functions ending with `A` use the ANSI encoding and the one ending with `W` use the unicode but there is only `ReadFile` and `ReadFileEx`

Output

```
09/15/2022  11:13 AM             2,560 main.c
09/15/2022  08:32 AM    <DIR>          ???????
09/15/2022  08:34 AM                 0 ??????????.txt
```

when using a loop and outputting each character using `%04X %c` I get

```
003F ?
003F ?
003F ?
003F ?
003F ?
003F ? 
003F ? 
003F ? 
003F ? 
003F ?
002E .
0074 t 
0078 x 
0074 t
```

How to deal with such problem once and for all so that it outputs any language to the screen

Comment: problem not in ReadFile. problem in printf

Comment: `ReadFile/Ex()` only knows about bytes, not text.  It is your responsibility to manage the text, converting/displaying it as needed. So, you have to know ahead of time, or use heuristics to discover, the actual encoding of the text so you can process it correctly. Also, your `grabOutput()` function does not have the correct signature for `CreateThread()`, as it is missing the `WINAPI` (`_stdcall`) calling convention.

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you please explain why does it print `3F` for each element in `Шифрование`, I know that it is `?` but I don't know how to convert it to hex value

Comment: `printf()` is interpreting the raw bytes in the wrong charset. `Шифрование` does not use a single-byte encoding for its characters. For example, in UTF-8, `Шифрование` is bytes `d0 a8 d0 b8 d1 84 d1 80 d0 be d0 b2 d0 b0 d0 bd d0 b8 d0 b5`. In UTF-16, it is bytes `28 04 38 04 44 04 40 04 3e 04 32 04 30 04 3d 04 38 04 35 04`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you be more specific, how do I use the right charset encoding

Comment: @loaded_dypper Please provide the code page of the console. (You can get that by running `chcp` from the console.) Also, please provide the encoding of the text being read.

Comment: You can't specify an encoding with `printf()`. You have to determine the right encoding being used for the raw bytes and then *convert* the data to an ANSI format that `printf()` can consume. Or, *convert* the data to a Unicode format (if it is not already) that you can use with `wprintf()`. Either way, your first task is to identify the actual encoding being used for the raw bytes. `ReadFile()` will not tell you that. So, either read the docs for the child app you are reading from, or else analyze the bytes manually. Can you provide an example of what the bytes actually look like?

Comment: You should also read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau what example exactly should I provide?

Comment: Can you please show the actual values of the bytes in the `buffer` after `ReadFile()` exits without error? Which BTW, you have 2 logic bugs in your reading code. You are not handling the possibility that `dwRead` may be 0 when `success` is `true`, indicating EOF when the child process exits. And, you are not accounting for the possibility that the `buffer` may not (and likely is not) null-terminated. You need something more like this: `success = ReadFile(...); if (!success || dwRead == 0) break; printf("%.*s", (int)dwRead, buffer);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the output of my program where `??????????.txt` is actually `Шифрование.txt`

Comment: Then the problem is not in your reading code, but is in the child app that you are reading from, it is not outputting non-ASCII characters to begin with. That is a data loss occurring inside the child app, so that is where you need to fix it (if you even have access to fix that app, that is). Nothing you can do about it in the reading app, the data is already lost before it reaches the reading loop.

Comment: You need to check the buffer in debugger memory window or the generated file in hex mode.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the buffer in debugger memory window or the generated file in hex mode, you need to use [_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170#example-use-_setmode-to-change-stdout) to set the file translation mode for `stdout` as @RemyLebeau said.
The following code is adapted from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62928984/15511041).
[image: Code]
[image]

Comment: my end goal is to be able to print all languages, looking at your answer i can only see the russian part

Comment: What's UTF8 destination??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by UTF8 destination

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT The solution you propose does not solve the OP's problem. You are assuming the OP's code is the one outputting bad data, but the OP's code in question is actually spawning an instance of `cmd.exe`, having it execute the `dir` command, and is then capturing that output to display it. The problem is, `dir`'s output is experiencing data loss before the data even reaches the OP's code. So your solution will not help solve that.